# Difference between Unicode format?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, string-formatting

I noticed something while uploading some unicode data to the database. When the content is uploaded throught textarea, is gets stored in `&#2325;` format, but when you personally type or paste the unicode and insert it hardcoded in php, then it would store in `à¤` format. But for both, the unicode character is same `क`.

Now please tell me the difference between the different formats of unicode characters. And how they affect the development. There has to be some limitations in those formats.

Comment: Tell us: what database, how you are connecting to it, what do you mean by  à¤ format?

Comment: @bmargulies The Database is MySQL, and is `à¤` the string text that is entered in the database when an unicode character "क" is inserted.

Comment: @Starx Then you have an encoding problem. When you enter "क", the database should store "क". I suspect your database [connection] is set to latin1 and not UTF-8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**& #2325;** is [markup used in HTML to represent a Unicode character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference)

If you hard code something in a php source file, Make sure you are opening it with editor that correctly displays text files with unicode characters in it.

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html is good place to know the basics of unicode.

UTF-8 encoding of क has the byte sequence **E0 A4**

Now if somebody interprets this as 8 bit [Latin encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) it will think it is two characters

you will see in the table in the above link E0 is à and A4 is ¤

Comment: I have read the basics, and the question is the difference about the formats, please note it. And I do use editors to code my PHP.

Comment: From your question it wasn't clear where do you see à¤ ? If you are seeing it your mysql db. I would double check if your db is aware of unicode and the connection to db is aware of unicode not to mention if the viewer that you are using to view the db row/column is aware of unicode

Comment: @Starx `utf8_encode` converts a Latin-1 string to UTF-8. If your string already is UTF-8, you don't need it. In fact, it'll mess up your string, as you can see.

Comment: @deceze, So clearify one thing, while querying `insert into sometable values("क");` it is stored as `à¤` in the table. So, php is messing this up.

Comment: @Starx No, you're messing up because either your database is configured to store Latin-1 and/or you're not telling your database to expect UTF-8. Google `SET NAMES utf8`.

Comment: @deceze, Actually you might know what is going wrong, when I copy the query and run it using phpmyadmin, the unicode remains as unicode, no fancy encoding at all. So, there must something I am missing, when i am querying through php. My field collation is set to utf8_unicode_ci, so what is going wrong?

Comment: @deceze, i just reset my db, table and field, all as utf8_general_ci as their collation, but still getting same results. And I have tried set names utf8; too.

Comment: @parapurarajkumar, thank you for the explanation. My question is answered and now I just need a way to fix this properly.

Answer (score 2):

> When the content is uploaded throught textarea, is gets stored in क format,

Forms **should not** submit content in a character-reference (`&#...;`) format.

**But** in reality, they do in most current browsers... but only when they can't submit the character in question in any other way. In this case, you can't tell whether the user originally typed `क` or `&#2325;`, it is a lossy encoding.

To avoid this, make sure you are serving your page in a charset that supports all possible Unicode characters. In practical terms this means always use UTF-8, and serve your page with the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header and/or the `<meta http-equiv="Content=Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>` element in the header. You'll then get all characters in simple, uncorrupted UTF-8 format.

Comment: Or add the `accept-charset="utf-8"` attribute to the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Well, as I am mentioned earlier in comments, I have taken every measure of ensuring that my system recognises UTF8 charset. Like Db, Tables, Fields, database connections and html metas also except the one @RemyLebeau-TeamB has suggested. I will just try it out.

Comment: `accept-charset` is not properly supported in IE; it will only use the charset in that attribute as a fallback, when the submitted characters don't fit the page's charset. Making sure the browser is rendering the page containing the form as UTF-8 is the necessary step; `accept-charset` is only of any use to catch the case when the user deliberately changes the View->Encoding in the browser (which is very unlikely), and in that case it can only be made effective by including a character in a hidden field that doesn't exist in any non-UTF encoding. Typically the Unicode Snowman is used for this.

Comment: So, then despite all these, how come I am still experiencing this prob.

Comment: You either haven't set the page's charset right (check View->Encoding in browser is UTF-8), or you've got unwanted processing of incoming data. Some PHP frameworks do silly unwanted things with incoming data due to misplaced security concerns. Post example code.